# Create ClusterRule with Kubernetes java client

Tags: java, kubernetes

I'm using fabric8 version 3.1.10 as my kuberenetes java client.
I need to create ClusterRule, but ClusterRole exist only in openshift package.
Is it possible that fabric8 didn't implement the rbac.authorization.k8s.io api group???

How can I create ClusterRole in GCloud, for example, using fabric8 client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Not all available type are part of the fabric8io/kubernetes-model which is used by the fabric8io/kubernetes-client.

I created an issue to keep track of it: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/1066